# how do dispatch the requests to different JSP pages from a single servlet in doGet method of servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a servlet with multiple methods calling in it based on getParameters in doPost..but the problem am facing is how do i dispatch the requests to different jsp pages in doGet method..

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Enumeration<String> en=request.getParameterNames();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Object paramNames = en.nextElement();
        String param=(String)paramNames;
        list.add(param);

    }   
    for (String string : list) {
        if(string.equalsIgnoreCase("minPrice")|| string.equalsIgnoreCase("maxPrice")){
            String minPrice = request.getParameter("minPrice");
            String maxPrice = request.getParameter("maxPrice"); 

            request.setAttribute("minamt", minPrice);
            request.setAttribute("maxamt", maxPrice);   
            request.setAttribute("totalProducts", filter.filterByPrice(min, max).size());
            request.setAttribute("filterByPrice", filter.filterByPrice(min, max));

            if(!filter.filterByPrice(min, max).isEmpty()){
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/filteredPricePage.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }else{
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Apologies..Products not available in this range, Try giving different range");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/priceFilter.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }else if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("minPromotion")|| string.equalsIgnoreCase("minPromotion")) {

            String minPromo = request.getParameter("minPromotion");
            String maxPromo = request.getParameter("maxPromotion"); 
            request.setAttribute("filterByPromotions", filter.filterByPromotion(min, max));
            request.setAttribute("totalProducts", filter.filterByPromotion(min, max).size());

            if(!filter.filterByPromotion(min, max).isEmpty()){
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/filteredPromotion.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }else{
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Apologies..Products not available in this range, Try giving different range");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/promotionFilter.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
```

SO i have two methods calling here and i have a list of navaigation links by pressing it should go to different jsps

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error is thrown?

Your Code looks ok but I think it could be the URI to the JSP:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/filteredPricePage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In most caces the URI `/WEB-INF/Views/filteredPricePage.jsp` is not accessable. Move your "Views" folder under "web" or look what path is registerd in your web.xml file for the views.

Hope that helps.